# Negation of a sentence

Tags: logic

Consider the following statement:

> All cats have tails.(1)

The negation of this statement is

> Some cats do not have tails. (2)

Now, someone can arrive at this statement by thinking that, 'hey, my cat does not have a tail'. So this statement can be negated by assuming that there exists atleast one cat which does not have a tail.
My first question is, is the statement **some cats have tails** equivalent to the statement (2)?
Why?
Can one assume that all cats have tails based on the statement 'some cats have tails'?. I think not.
So can I write it as a negation of (1) ?

Consider this statement :

> Not all cats have tails

How does this differ from (2)?

Like I said, my cat does not have a tail. So can't I say that **not all cats have tails** since the first statement was based on the assumption that all cats have tails?

And finally, for a statement to be true, should it be absolutely true?
Consider my example. All cats necessarily don't possess a tail. It has been scientifically proved that a cat has a tail, but due to some reasons (eg:a fight), it may lose a tail. Does my statement cease to exist as a statement at that precise moment since a statement should be either completely true or completely false, but not both?
Also by keeping the above sentences in mind, can I say that the sentence  **Spiderman is a Superhero** a statement?

PS: I don't have much experience in this . So could you kindly avoid the usage of symbols while explaining this? ie. Would you use plain english?

Thank you

Comment: The negation of "All are P" is "Some are not-P" that - in general - does not mean that "Some are P". The meaning of "Some" is "At least one (maybe more)"

Comment: And "Not all Cats have Tails" is exactly the same ad "Some Cat has no tail". In general $\lnot \forall x Px$ is equivalent to $\exists x \lnot Px$

Comment: "for a statement to be true, should it be absolutely true? " What is "ablsotely" true?

Comment: If some are not P isn't equivalent to some are P?

Comment: Consider a cat born with no tails. Obviously i can use its presence to negate my first statement. What I meant is, for a statement to be true, should it be universally acceptable? Does it permit exceptions?

Comment: "Some integers are not irrational." This is can be proved because $1$ is an integer, and $1$ is not irrational. Now consider "Some integers are irrational". Is that equivalent?

Comment: "Some cats do not have tails", does not exclude the possibility that "no cat has a tail". If this is the case, then "some cats have tails" is false. Similarly, the last statement does not exclude the possibility that "all cats have tails". In that case, the former statement is false. So, no, the two statements are not equivalent.

Comment: In logic, a universal statement can not have exceptions. So, "All cats have tails" is false, if there is even one cat without a tail, no matter for the reasons.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair the statement all integers are not irrational does not  explicitly say that all integers are rational. ie. There exists some chance that an integer is not rational. In such a context, you can say that this assumption is false only because of the fact that you aldready knew that all integers are rational. In the same sense, why can't I say that the statement 'Some integers are irrational' is equivalent to 'some integers are not irrational '

Comment: @Aris Makrides. So some integers are not irrational simply include the possibility that all integers are rational. If so,' all integers are irrational' is not true. The statement 'some integers are irrational  include the possibility that all integers are irrational. Then, 'all integers are rational' is false. So these two statements are not equivalent. Am I correct?

Comment: I have another doubt. But it is about converse and contrapositive statements. Should I make a new question? Or can I include it in this question?

Comment: The statement "all integers are not irrational" *does* say "all integers are rational" (at least, under conventional logic). And note that "explicitly" is unnecessary because logic does not allow for implicit meanings. Statements must be well-defined. So it either says something, or it does not. It never "implies" something except in the strict logical sense of direct proof. However you would be correct that the statement *I* made, "some integers are not irrational" does not say "all integers are rational". But it also does not say "some integers are irrational". That was my point.